# how to enable mobile tapping and arrow keys using p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js, mobile-development

I created a game using p5js, works fine on the desktop. I need help in making the game mobile compatible. Trying using thunkable and the game is displaying, but not great also the keys are not working.

**How to enable mobile tapping and arrow keys using p5js?**

Below is my game URL on GitHub url. https://crazylegoid.github.io/The-Treasure-of-King-Arthur-2/

I need suggestions or samples.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage p5.js array `touches` to create a simple joystick interface for your game.

You can access x,y coordinates of all touch points on your phone screen through for example `touches[0].x` and `touches[0].y`.

[image]

Here is a demo you can try on your phone: https://p5js-simple-joystick.glitch.me/ This demo supports tapping and has a joystick that works as arrow keys.

You can take a look at the code for the demo from here: [https://glitch.com/~p5js-simple-joystick](https://glitch.com/%7Ep5js-simple-joystick)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement the approach in my game.